# Stuck on a SQL Syntax error

Tags: mysql, workbench

I'm a little bit stuck with my SQL models. I use MySQL Workbench to create models graphically and i greated a schema which i think fits my use case. However i can't synchronnise with the database because it gives me the following error. Maybe someone else can see what i did wrong. Apparantly i'm blind currently...

> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL DEFAULT
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>         `last_activity` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>         ' at line 6

```
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topas`.`user` (
          `id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          `email` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          `password` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
          `created_at`  NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
          `last_activity` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
          UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC),
          UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),
          UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC),
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8

SQL script execution finished: statements: 3 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Thanks.

Comment: The column type is missing. It should be `created_at DATETIME NULL ...` or `created_at TIMESTAMP NULL ...`. Check the documentation of the `CREATE TABLE` statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
`created_at`  NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

is missing type definition. It should be:

```
`created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is missing a data type

```
`created_at`  NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

You will need to set it to either `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`:

```
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the column type for `created_at` column.
should be:

```
`created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```